# What does the SSS represent in the org.apache.log4j.helpers.ISO8601DateFormat?

Tags: java, date, log4j

The [JavaDoc](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/helpers/ISO8601DateFormat.html) says:

> Formats a Date in the format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS" for example
>   "1999-11-27 15:49:37,459".

Are they milliseconds from 000-999? [The summary of the international standard date and time notation](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/iso-time.html) makes no mention of milliseconds.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It formats Date. In Date formatting "SSS" pattern means milliseconds from 000 to 999, so you are correct.

Comment: Correct answer. Note that in [Java 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), the new [java.time package](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) uses a resolution of nanoseconds instead of milliseconds. That means you can have up to 6 digits of a fractional second, `SSSSSS`.

Comment: @Basil Bourque: a nanosecond is 1E-9 seconds, so that's 9 fractional digits

Comment: @Lolo Thank you… I stand corrected. The new java.time package has nanosecond potential resolution. A [nanosecond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) is 1/1,000,000,000 of a second. So it renders String representations with up to 9 digits of a fractional second. My incorrect comment above said `6` when it should have said `9`. As the [documentation for java.time.ZonedDateTime](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) says, the time portion can look like this: `13:45.30.123456789`